# Determining if a string is an Isogram

Tags: python

**The Task**:
Write a program that checks if a word supplied as the argument is an Isogram. An Isogram is a word in which no letter occurs more than once.

Create a method called is_isogram that takes one argument, a word to test if it's an isogram. This method should return a tuple of the word and a boolean indicating whether it is an isogram.

If the argument supplied is an empty string, return the argument and False: (argument, False). If the argument supplied is not a string, raise a TypeError with the message 'Argument should be a string'.

Example:

```
is_isogram("abolishment")
```

Expected result:

```
("abolishment", True)
```

The Visible test

```
from unittest import TestCase

class IsogramTestCases(TestCase):
  def test_checks_for_isograms(self):
    word = 'abolishment'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, True),
      msg="Isogram word, '{}' not detected correctly".format(word)
    )

  def test_returns_false_for_nonisograms(self):
    word = 'alphabet'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, False),
      msg="Non isogram word, '{}' falsely detected".format(word)
    )

  def test_it_only_accepts_strings(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as context:
      is_isogram(2)
      self.assertEqual(
        'Argument should be a string',
        context.exception.message,
        'String inputs allowed only'
      )
```

**My Solution:**

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if type(word) != str:
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')

    elif word == "":
      return (word, False)
    else:
        word = word.lower()
        for char in word:
            if word.count(char) > 1:
                return (word, False)
            else:
                return (word, True)
```

**But it the function refuses to pass some hidden test: What is wrong with my solution? Is there another elegant way of writing this function?**

Comment: `return (word,True)` should be outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Please fix your indentation in your code snippet

Comment: While this isn't off-topic here, you may be able to find more constructive feedback on the Code Review SE (codereview.stackexchange.com) (since your code's mostly working, and only failing what's supposedly an edge case).

Comment: @Jules Thanks, I will do just that

Comment: @Jules I think this is just fine for SO; the code requires de-bugging and and a better solution is asked for.

Comment: Nifemi, you might want to look at my answer, it should solve your issue. If it does not solve it, let me know and maybe I can help further

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure your search should be case insensitive so perhaps you should remove `word = word.lower()`, but your main issue is `return` terminates the function so you current code needs to only `return True` after all tests have been conducted (i.e. outside of the loop):

```
for char in word:
    if word.count(char) > 1:
        return (word, False)
return (word, True)
```

---

Anyway, a better way is to use `set()` to remove all duplicates from your string and then compare the lengths; also use `isinstance()` to check if `word` is a string. You can use `if w` to check for empty strings . You don't need parentheses with `return`, the comma is enough to `return` a tuple:

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if isinstance(word,str):
        w = word.lower() # assuming you want a case in-sensitive search
        return word, len(w) == len(set(w)) if w else False
    else:
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
```

Examples:

```
is_isogram('abolishment')
# ('abolishment', True)
is_isogram('happy')
# ('happy', False)
is_isogram('')
# ('', False)
is_isogram(1)
# TypeError: Argument should be a string
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried in this way:

```
def isogram(n):
 if not isinstance(n, str):
    return n,False
 elif len(n) < 1:
    return n,False
 n = n.lower()
 if len(n) == len(set(n)):
    return n,True
 else:
    return n,False
```

- The second line checks if the input n is a string, if it isn't it returns    False.
- The line 4 checks if the length of the input is smaller than 1, in that case the input is empty and we cannot check if it is an isogram or not.
- 'n = n.lower()' in line 6 assures us that the input becomes a string with lowercase letters.
- In line 7 we check if the length of the input is equal to the length of the set(n). The function set() converts a collection or a sequence or an iterator object into a set. For example: set('lists') returns {'s', 't', 'l', 'i'}, as you can see the letter 's' which appears twice in 'lists', does not appear in the set. This is useful to check if the length of the set is equal to the length of the input, if there is a letter which appears twice in the input the condition is False.

I hope this explanation makes the script clear.

Comment: comments on what the code does would be appreciated

Comment: I've edited my comment above adding some explanations. I hope it helps you. @Qchmqs

Comment: I already understood it tho, but having a better quality answer is good for everyone

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_isogram(string):
    if type(string) != str:
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
    elif string == " ":
        return (string, False)
    else:
        for i in string:
            if string.count(i) > 1:
                return (string, False)
    return (string, True)
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how to implement and use the code above

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this

**"But it the function refuses to pass some hidden test: What is wrong with my solution? Is there another elegant way of writing this function?"**

i.e refuses to pass the tests is pretty simple.

```
elif word == "":
```

should be

```
elif word == " ":
```

as per the unit test

```
if argument==" " :
    return(argument,False)
```

You are forgetting the whitespace. Hope this helps the next person who comes searching.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. If there are more than one digit it will be added to a new string. If this new string is empty the function will return True. Else False. Only " if word.count(char) > 1: " won´t do it. At least not for me.

```
def isagram (word):
    if not isinstance(word, str):
        return (False, word)
    if not word:
        return (False, word)
    word.lower()
    multi_char = ''
    for char in word:
        if word.count(char) > 1:
            multi_char += char
    return (False, word) if multi_char else (True, word)
```

Comment: Sorry, I added some more explanation. Try it. I´m sure there are much better solutions but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve the problem:

```
def is_isogram(argument):
  word_seen=set()
  if type(argument) != str:
    raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
  if argument==" " :
    return(argument,False)
  argument.lower()
   for letter in argument:
    if letter in word_seen:
      return(argument,False)
    word_seen.add(letter)
  return (argument,True)
```

Equivalently, I also tried the following to remove all spaces in strings:

```
def is_isogram(argument):
  word_seen=set()
  if type(argument) != str:
    raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
  if argument==" " :
    return(argument,False)
  argument.lower()
  argument = ''.join(argument.split())
  for letter in argument:
    if letter in word_seen:
      return(argument,False)
    word_seen.add(letter)
  return (argument,True)
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it here:

def is_isogram(word):

```
for letter in word:
    if word.count(letter) > 1:
        return False
else:
    return True
```

print is_isogram("Hello")

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_Isogram(words):
cover_words = words.lower()

letter_list = []

for letter in cover_words:
    if letter.isalpha():
        if letter in letter_list:
            return False
        letter_list.append(letter)
return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
      print(is_Isogram('Machine'))
      print(is_Isogram('Geeks'))`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the last part of your suggested solution:

```
    for char in word:
        if word.count(char) > 1:
            return (word, False)
        else:
            return (word, True)
```

`return` will end the function, hence the `for` loop will always exit after counting repetitions of the first letter and never check the other ones.

If your word has a first letter which is unique, the function will return True.

I believe this is a bug and this is my corrected suggestion:

```
    for char in word:
        if word.count(char) > 1:
            return (word, False)
    return (word, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import collections

def is_isogram(word):
    if not isinstance(word, str):
        raise TypeError('Argument should be a string')
    most_common = collections.Counter(word).most_common(1)
    if most_common:
        char, freq = most_common[0]
        return (word, freq == 1)
    else:
        return (word, False)
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need an extra conditional statement to check if the characters in the word are solely alphabets (i.e. no numbers or symbols) whilst checking if the characters are repeated:

```
def is_isogram(word):
    if type(word) != str:
        raise TypeError("Argument should be a string")
    if len(word) < 1:
        return (word, False)
    word = word.lower()

    for char in word:
        if word.count(char) > 1 or \
        char not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":  # this checks that the char is an alphabet
            return (word, False)
    return (word, True)
```

I guess this should help.

Answer (score -1):

i found this correct

```
    def is_isogram(word):

          if type(word)!=str:
            raise TypeError("Argument should be a String") 
          elif word.strip()=="":
              return(word,False)   else:
              word =word.lower()
             for char in word:
              if word.count(char) >1:
                return (word ,False)
              else:
                return(word ,True)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some text.. Whats the difference, ..?